# not able to set background color in given styles

Tags: css

i trying to change background color on mouse over.

i have this css code

```
table.subform{width: 550px}
table.subform tr td{padding: 3px}
table.subform tr td:first-child{text-align: right}
table.subform2{width: 100%}
table.subform2 tr td{padding: 5px;}
table.subform2 tr td:first-child{text-align: right;background-color: #E3E3E3;font-weight: bold;width: 50%;border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;padding-right: 10px}
table.subform2 tr td:last-child{text-align: left;background-color: #f1f1f1;vertical-align: top}
table.subform2 tr:hover{color: #082;background-color: #FFF}
```

as you can see in last line **table.subform2 tr:hover** when someone mouse hover TR then full TR's background color have to be change

Comment: please post full example using [jsffiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrYUJ/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are define `background-color` to it's **TD** that's why it's not visible. Write like this:

```
table.subform2 tr:hover td{color: #082;background-color: #FFF}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZrYUJ/2/

Answer (score 3):

The background doesn't change, because you have defined `background-color` in `table.subform2 tr td:first-child` and `...:last-child`. When you define no background-color or define a background-color on `... tr` only, the background-color changes.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56RyP/1/), the middle column.

Change the last line to

```
table.subform2 tr:hover td{color: #082;background-color: #FFF}
```

this selects the `td` element and changes the background-color accordingly.

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrYUJ/1/)

Comment: please check budde's answer

Answer (score 0):

Write your HTML because if something is wrong in it it is possible reason `tr:hover` to not working. And make sure the browser is not old because `tr:hover` is not supported everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
table.subform2 tr:hover td{color: #082;background-color: #FFF}
```

instead. Because you have set the background color of the child td's.

Also tr:hover does not work in some older browsers. You can use javascript for fixing this.

http://jsfiddle.net/DK5x4/